# Python jose.jwt.decode fails on rs256 algorithm

Tags: python, jwt, decoding, python-jose

https://github.com/Ofineo/coffee-shop

I try to decode a JWT with jose.JWT.decode  in Auth.py but I always get an error:
`jose.exceptions.JWKError: Could not deserialize key data`.
After a lot of investigations, I pinned it down to the RS256 algorithm. 
This is exactly where it crashes:

```
payload = jwt.decode(
            token,
            rsa_key,
            algorithms=ALGORITHMS,
            audience=API_AUDIENCE,
            issuer='https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/',
        )
```

This is a valid token example:

`eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ik9USXpNakl6UkVZMFJEQXdNRGN3UTBFNVF6TTBNekE0TURNMVF6bERRVGRFUVRNeE1VUXpNdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL29maW5lby5ldS5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiYXV0aDB8NWU3NGQ0OTAzODYwMWQwYmU5MWI4NDM3IiwiYXVkIjoiY29mZmVlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg0NzE0OTY3LCJleHAiOjE1ODQ3MjIxNjcsImF6cCI6ImRWdlZ3N200MlpRUkdBWmptZkE0ekkxYWQ0dXZ0S0Q4Iiwic2NvcGUiOiIiLCJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6WyJkZWxldGU6ZHJpbmtzIiwiZ2V0OmRyaW5rcy1kZXRhaWwiLCJwYXRjaDpkcmlua3MiLCJwb3N0OmRyaW5rcyJdfQ.xviLIr5euhsWlgQZiJZV9JOL0hA3Fz_jYwfhjPj-a8Zf7YySp1RMmzTVw8X7xKpkYZZlaaR47kYL42I_y172UX7_ABkQ8nYqJXqIa_g9ZFYhnAqk4PN0aIAjO8F6HLPaSh6c6DdAdMBeODS0p8JPPSzjWd5AKzjqzff5a7FEcnXZqgB-Ac01OECAdViodeKJk7dBnuKfD2UlmmEHM-2xQC2ZM0zO17qTJ-zia0lHy3Z6MK9-nbf4wxlFidTIWD9WyvqJxCg40YUMkn2YrILfdIGvxFCRyBisQp7Cu-UsOEa0irgNf5zUXmYLhp1DgV-fFxTfRB0nX6O5Sf29tfOMNQ`

It decodes no problem in http://www.JWT.io

This is my code. I call the requires_auth function from an @app.route

```
import json
from flask import request, _request_ctx_stack, abort
from functools import wraps
from jose import jwt
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys


AUTH0_DOMAIN = 'ofineo.eu.auth0.com'
ALGORITHMS = ['RS256']
API_AUDIENCE = 'coffee'

# AuthError Exception
'''
AuthError Exception
A standardized way to communicate auth failure modes
'''


class AuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error, status_code):
        self.error = error
        self.status_code = status_code


# Auth Header


def get_token_auth_header():
    """Obtains the Access Token from the Authorization Header
    """
    auth = request.headers.get('Authorization', None)
    if not auth:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'authorization_header_missing',
            'description': 'Authorization header is expected.'
        }, 401)

    parts = auth.split()
    if parts[0].lower() != 'bearer':
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Authorization header must start with "Bearer".'
        }, 401)

    elif len(parts) == 1:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Token not found.'
        }, 401)

    elif len(parts) > 2:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Authorization header must be bearer token.'
        }, 401)

    token = parts[1]

    return token


def check_permissions(permission, payload):
    if 'permissions' not in payload:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_claims',
            'description': 'Permissions not included in JWT.'
        }, 400)

    if permission not in payload['permissions']:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'unauthorized',
            'description': 'Permission not found.'
        }, 403)
    return True


def verify_decode_jwt(token):
    jsonurl = urlopen(f'https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())

    unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    rsa_key = {}
    if 'kid' not in unverified_header:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Authorization malformed.'
        }, 401)

    for key in jwks['keys']:

        if key['kid'] == unverified_header['kid']:
            rsa_key = {
                'kty': key['kty'],
                'kid': key['kid'],
                'use': key['use'],
                'n': key['n'],
                'e': key['e']
            }
    if rsa_key:
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(
                token,
                rsa_key,
                algorithms=ALGORITHMS,
                audience=API_AUDIENCE,
                issuer='https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/',
            )

            return payload

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'token_expired',
                'description': 'Token expired.'
            }, 401)

        except jwt.JWTClaimsError:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_claims',
                'description': 'Incorrect claims. Please, check the audience and issuer.'
            }, 401)

        except jwt.JWTError:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid signature',
                'description': 'the signature is invalid in some way'
            }, 401)

        except Exception:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_header',
                'description': 'Unable to parse authentication token.'
            }, 400)

    raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_header',
                'description': 'Unable to find the appropriate key.'
            }, 400)


def requires_auth(permission=''):
    def requires_auth_decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            token = get_token_auth_header()
            try:
                payload = verify_decode_jwt(token)
                check_permissions(permission, payload)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                abort(401)

            return f(payload, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return requires_auth_decorator
```

Am I using the library correctly??

Comment: Thanks for adding code to work with. Next time please add a comment for those who asked about details, to notify them of changes. Now I tried your code, esp. the `verify_decode_jwt` function, and it works fine for me, I just got an exception  `jose.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError: Signature has expired`, which is normal,  and after adding `options={'verify_exp':False},` to the `decode` call, the payload was decoded without any exceptions. I can't reproduce your exception.

Comment: I got this error in my case `Unable to parse authentication token`